# Full text search returns different results on test and live

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I will try to explain this issue as properly as I can. It's really weird in my mind, hopefully  some of you guys have an idea of what might be wrong.

I have built a website with a search function, which uses full text search in MySQL, and searches in a table that is a dictionary.

I have set `ft_min_word_len = 1` and `ft_stopword_file = ""` on both my test (windows xampp) and live (ubuntu 12.04) server.

Now, on my localhost test server if I search for example the word "hello", it returns around 20 entries from my dictionary. If I search for "hello" (same) on my live server, no results get returned.

However, if I search for example the word "kyuu" (japanese word) on my test server, I get around 50 results. On my live server I get 2 results.

So this means that it does search and it does return some results sometimes. There's just something very weird with the result it grabs on the live server.

Any ideas? It seems almost as if the live server only searches a part of the table or something? Or it runs out of memory and quits in the middle of the search or something? I don't know...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? Facing same issue right now.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but suggestion:

do u have the exact indexes and table setup on the live server? Even a variation in encoding can throw it off.. Maybe you should run the table repair quick option

[MySql Repair Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repair-table.html)