# SQL - Why does same full text search return a different result on a different server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I have a same table with full text catalog on 2 different servers. Both the table in both server are indexed and setup the same. I've tried restart the services and rebuilding the catalog. When running the same query in both server, the RANK in FREETEXTTABLE shown in both server are showing differently. Below are the sample query.

```
SELECT *COLUMNS*
FROM TABLE
INNER JOIN FreeTextTable (TABLE, INDEXEDCOLUMN, N'"Sabariah Mohamed Ali" or "Ali Mohamed Sabariah"', 100) as KEY_TABLE ON TABLE.INDEX = KEY_TABLE.[KEY]  
WHERE KEY_TABLE.rank > 30

Select *COLUMNS*
from TABLE
Inner Join Containstable (TABLE, INDEXEDCOLUMN, N'"*Sabariah" or "Sabariah*" 
or "*Mohamed" or "Mohamed*"', 100) as KEY_TABLE on TABLE.INDEX = 
KEY_TABLE.[KEY]  
where KEY_TABLE.rank > 30
```

The indexed column in the table contains "Sabariah Binti Mohamed Ali". So, it should return the result but when i checked the RANK in KEY_TABLE, both server returns different number.

I think my problem is similar to this, [Full text search returns different results on test and live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192082/full-text-search-returns-different-results-on-test-and-live)

Edit: Found a similar issue, tried the solution provided, create a dummy table, create the index and catalog, doesn't work as well.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a5532c9a-ece2-40cb-a8ac-4f53ba96175c/problem-with-rank-on-freetexttable?forum=sqldatabaseengine#f51bb4a9-725b-499f-961a-9492bed0a1f0

Answer (score 0):

According to [How Search Query Results Are Ranked (Full-Text Search)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142524(v=sql.105).aspx)

> When an index is built, statistics are collected for use in ranking.
>   The process of building a full-text catalog does not directly result
>   in a single index structure. Instead, the Full-Text Engine for SQL
>   Server creates intermediate indexes as data is indexed. The Full-Text
>   Engine then merges these indexes into a larger index as needed. This
>   process can be repeated many times. The Full-Text Engine then conducts
>   a "master merge" that combines all of the intermediate indexes into
>   one large master index.
>
> Statistics are collected at each intermediate index level. The
>   statistics are merged when the indexes are merged. Some statistical
>   values can only be generated during the master merging process.
>
> While ranking a query result set, SQL Server uses statistics from the
>   largest intermediate index. This depends on whether intermediate
>   indexes have been merged or not. As a result, ranking statistics can
>   vary in accuracy if the intermediate indexes have not been merged.
>   This explains why the same query can return different rank results
>   over time as full-text indexed data is added, modified, and deleted,
>   and as the smaller indexes are merged.
>
> To minimize the size of the index and computational complexity,
>   statistics are often rounded.

In short: Ranking is based on statistics that are collected and refined gradually. Data chunk statistics are combined and some rounding is taking place. There is no particular deterministic repeatable pattern to how crawler indexes chunks even on the same server, let alone different servers. Anything can come into play like table actual store sort order, storage pagination, cores and shared memory pools availability at the time the indexing occurs.

**Update following comments:**

For the experiment I ran this (Example A off [CONTAINSTABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql)) several times on *the very same* SQL Server 2016 Express

```
CREATE TABLE Flags (
  Country nvarchar(30),
  FlagColors varchar(200),
  CONSTRAINT FlagKey PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Country)
);

INSERT Flags VALUES ('France', 'Blue and White and Red');  
INSERT Flags VALUES ('Italy', 'Green and White and Red');  
INSERT Flags VALUES ('Tanzania', 'Green and Yellow and Black and Yellow and Blue');  
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG TestFTCat;
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Flags(FlagColors) KEY INDEX FlagKey ON TestFTCat;  
GO

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'; --< "Crucial value"

SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Flags, FlagColors, 'Green or Black') ORDER BY RANK DESC;  

DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON Flags;
GO
DROP FULLTEXT CATALOG TestFTCat;
GO
DROP TABLE Flags;
GO
```

Please note the `"Crucial value"`: time allowed for the fulltext index to populate.
1 to 5 seconds and the results are

```
Tanzania    32
Italy       16
```

Any longer than 5 seconds and the results are

```
Tanzania    48
Italy       32
```

... and that's literally the same server and the data as simple as can be.

Comment: Sorry if I’m asking the wrong question. But the rank in both server differs by quite a lot. Looking at the data, the index column in both server are having the same value but the rank differs by 20+. Is that considered normal?

Comment: As far as I understand the rank is there only to order search results. As long as the results of `containstable` ordered by rank are the same the absolute rank values are pretty much irrelevant.